# contentbox integration with oracle on lucee server

Tags: oracle, ubuntu-12.04, railo, coldbox, lucee

I installed the following software in my machine successfully.

- Virtual Machine (VM).
- Ubuntu 12.04 32bit.
- Oracle 10g Express edition 32bit.
- Lucee (lucee-4.5.1.000-pl0-linux-installer.run)
- Contentbox

After above all installation I go `http://localhost:8888/lucee/admin/server.cfm` for check configuration all are working fine.
Next I go to this URL `http://localhost:8888/contentbox/` for the configuration of `contentbox` with oracle database, when I go to create data source, there is no 'oracle database' in dropdown list of database

[image: https://imgh.us/Snap_2.png]
<sub>(source: [imgh.us](https://imgh.us/Snap_2.png))</sub>

Can anyone help me at this point?
Is `contentbox` integration possible with oracle?

Comment: I also replied to your thread in the ColdBox Google group.  Please try to post a question on one forum at a time.  Note also, there is a ContentBox Google Group as well.

Comment: Where is the `web.xml` file because I did not find any file there to add my mapping for running `contentbox`

Comment: This isn't the right place to have that discussion since this question is regarding Oracle support.  Please reply on the applicable mailing list thread.

Answer (score 1):

We have not fully certified ContentBox on Oracle at this point.  However, I am glad to help you out and do that if you can provide feedback and debug it.

Comment: I have also tried another way by creating the `datasource` in `lucee` and then for `contentbox` entered that `datasource` name but it gives me error  after few seconds showing the query error `table or view does not exists`